# Change default primary and secondary colors in Materialize + Meteor

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, material-design, materialize

I'm using meteor with the materialize package for MaterialUI.

How can I **change the default** primary and secondary **colors** that this library uses? 
Or any other settings/variables?

I mean, I know I can go into the `/meteor/locals/` folder and change it manually, but I don't believe this is the right way to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using `poetic:materialize-scss`. Here's the [link](https://atmospherejs.com/poetic/materialize-scss) which includes a sample of how to setup and change the primary color. Secondary color change is practically the same.

Comment: How does this lib differ from materialize? It specifically says to remove materialize in the docs, which is strange :)

Comment: Also, there are many material design libs for meteor - which one would you recommend? `poetic:materialize-scss`?

Comment: I recommended this package because it sets up your style sheets so you can incorporate and overwrite scss variables. I switched to it about 2 months ago and haven't switched back.